# How to call GitHub Copilot Chat from my VS Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to write a vscode extension that can launch/trigger GitHub Copilot Chat to the do prompt. The expected use case looks like this:

1. User select a piece of code
2. User execute `Source Action` with my command, then my command able to send custom prompt to input box of the GitHub Copilot Chat and send it to get results.

Is that possible at this moment?